# Sheet Specific macros

Tags: excel, worksheet, visual-studio-macros

I have a workbook with three excel sheets in it.
I want a user to be able to copy data from the third sheet which is result of calculations in the second sheet.
How ever, the code I am using

```
'The code for the Macro
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim col As String
Dim msg As String
col = Split(Target.Address(1, 0), "AOS")(0)
'Permet d'éviter les modifications des modifications manuelles des cellules calculées automatiquement
If Intersect(Target, Sheets("AOS").Range("A3:AP100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'We're going to make a change, so turn this off
'so that macro doesn't get called infinitely
Sheets("AOS").Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("AOS").Application.Undo
MsgBox "Can't touch this!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error !!!!!"
Sheets("AOS").Application.EnableEvents = True
```

It is also undo changes made in second sheet.
Seems like, Sheets("AOS").Application.Undo is not working as it should be.

Any Suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `SelectionChange` event, you should be using the `Change` event. `SelectionChange` occurs every time the selection is changed, so when you use Undo it is reversing the last reversible action, which might have happened in a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before
>   running the macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It
>   cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands.